# IIS 6 authentication prompt when website is cloned

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, iis-6, windows-authentication

I have set up a copy of a website on a server and think I have replicated the folder permissions and the IIS settings, but I am getting a Windows authentication prompt, once I login with my admin details the site loads.

Any help with this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you using IE or another browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you untick "Windows Authentication" and tick "Anonymous". That comes on by default so 90% that is your problem.

Comment: Did you iisreset? Is web.config the same?

Comment: The site is a copy of one on th esame box that doesn't require the authentication so that rules out the web.config. IIS reset didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

It could happen also if proxy is set and the address is not marked as local intranet.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your new site is in the list of trusted sites